# Label element inside component

Tags: html, angular, select, label

When I run Lighthouse on my local project it returns the following:

> Form elements do not have associated labels

For inputs I've used `id="<input_id>"`, adding `for="<input_id>"`to its label. But now, I have a component for selecting the country, which is responsible for loading the list of countries.

```html
<form name="notificationDetailForm" [formGroup]="form">
  <div class="key-input">
    <label for="country-label">Country</label>
    <country-selector id="country-label" formControlName="country"></country-selector>
  </div>
</form>
```

So, label is separated from the select tag, which is inside the `country-selector` component:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry">
  <option [ngValue]="null" disabled selected>-- Select country --</option>
  <option *ngFor="let country of countries$ | async" [ngValue]="country">
    {{ country.name }}
  </option>
</select>
```

I have tried using `aria-labelledby` in the form component but it is the same.

My question is: How can I make the label reference the select tag inside the component?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it through via an input property

country-selector.ts

```js
@Input() controlId: string;
```

country-selector.html (other html

```html
<select [id]="controlId" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry">
  <option [ngValue]="null" disabled selected>-- Select country --</option>
  <option *ngFor="let country of countries$ | async" [ngValue]="country">
    {{ country.name }}
  </option>
</select>
```

parent.html

```html
<country-selector controlId="country-label" formControlName="country">
</country-selector>
```

You will probably need to do a similar thing with `formControlName` - avoid using `@Input()` property names that clash with the Angular directive names.

The problem with your approach is that you are assigning the id to the parent control itself (inspect the HTML that is generated). So the label never gets associated with the `<select>`.

Comment: Thank you, Kurt. 

I already knew this way, but it seems a bit dirty.

For the formControlName I'm extending the SelectControlValueAccessor interface, so it's like a native element and I don't need to create an input property.